# Magento 1.x How to get order Total amount in my custom module page?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, custom, grand-total

How to get order total amount in my custom file ?

Comment: Can you please explain in brief. Thanks.

Comment: check my answer @Lokesh M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try Following way...

```
$order = Mage::getSingleton('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);

$order->getGrandTotal();
```

Comment: Its working Thank you Mr.Rakesh :)

Answer (score 0):

Basically we get order total amount like this :

```
$order = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->loadByIncrementId($orderId); // get order

$order->getGrandTotal();
```

Comment: I got the Order_Id.. But can't get order total amount..can you please tell me some other way To get order total amount ?

Comment: This is my code used in controller file                                                             
`$order = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->load($orderId);`                                    
`$totalPrice = $order->getGrandTotal();`                                                   
`echo $totalPrice; exit;`

Comment: try with var_dump($order->getData()); to get array for all data. than check.

Comment: please check again which i update my answer.

Comment: `$order = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->load($orderId);
$orders = var_dump($order->getData());
print_r($orders);`                        
                                                                                                                              Output :   array(0)

Comment: $order = Mage::getSingleton('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);

$order->getGrandTotal();